# I can't get the string from ActionListener to different class in Java

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener, jcombobox

I created a JComboBox and JButton to submit information. I need the information to be sent to a different class to sort it out with a switch method. But it looks like the string created inside the ActionListener is not recognized by a different class.

```
public Main() {
    final JComboBox comboB = new JComboBox(b);          //add int b in here for array
    comboB.setBounds(50, 30, 123, 20);
    contentPane.add(comboB);

    JButton btnTest = new JButton("Test");
    btnTest.setBounds(300, 350, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnTest);

    btnTest.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String s = (String)comboB.getSelectedItem();
        }
    });
 }
```

How do I make it so that String s can be recognized by other classes? I have a separate class that will change action depending on what is selected from ComboBox, but I just can't seem to get this information out. Thank you.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or combinations of them, along with layout padding & borders for white space. 3) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: Make the string an instance variable, preferably `private`, and create a get method like `public String getS() { return this.s; }`

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, other objects need some way to register an `ActionListener` to the combo box.  I would suggest providing a `addActionListener` method to your class, this would act as a proxy method and simple pass the call onto `comboB`

Secondly, this means `comboB` is going to need to be a class instance variable

Thirdly, the other classes are going to need to determine if the action originiated from the combo box or not, for example.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() instanceof JComboBox) {
        JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
        String s = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
    }
}
```

Now, there's not a lot of context available to the question, but, personally, I would normally either use a model of some kind that your UI class would update and/or a `PropertyChangeListener` that other classes could register against and monitor for changes to the "properties" of the your main class.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to create a private method and have the combo call that. Then you just navigate to your component/class, and perform the action.

```
    public Main() {
    final JComboBox comboB = new JComboBox(b);          //add int b in here for array
    comboB.setBounds(50, 30, 123, 20);
    contentPane.add(comboB);

    JButton btnTest = new JButton("Test");
    btnTest.setBounds(300, 350, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnTest);

    btnTest.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String s = (String)comboB.getSelectedItem();
            myMethodThatProcessesS(s);

        }
    });
 }

private void myMethodThatProcessesS(String s) {
     contentPane.getSomeOtherComponent().doSOmething(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since java swing implements the [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) you can pass the JComboBox's model reference to other objects.

Models implement the observer pattern and therefore the other objects can register themself if they need to get notified immediatly when the model changes.

```
public class Main {
    public initializeComponent(OtherClass otherClass) {
        ...
        JComboBox comboBox = ...;
        ComboBoxModel comboBoxModel = comboBox.getModel();
        otherClass.setComboBoxModel(comboBoxModel);
    }
}

public class OtherClass {

    private ComboBoxModel comboBoxModel;

    public void setComboBoxModel(ComboBoxModel comboBoxModel) {
        this.comboBoxModel = comboBoxModel;
        ListDataListener listener = ...;
        comboBoxModel.addListDataListener(listener);
    }

    public String getSelectedItem(){
        Object selectedItem = comboBoxModel.getSelectedItem();
        ...
    }
}
```